# C++ enum class as a variable template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I'm trying to optimize out some function at compile time by using an enum class as a template parameter.

Say for example

```cpp
enum class Color { RED, BLACK };
```

Now, I would like to define a method

```cpp
void myMethod<Color c> () {
 if( c == Color::RED ) { ... }
 if( c == Color::BLACK ) { ... }
}
```

And I would like the compiler to make 2 copies of `myMethod` and eliminate the dead code during the optimisation (it's for CUDA kernels so speed and register usage is important to me)

However, seems like when I call the method using

```
void doSomething( const Color c ) {
 myMethod<c>();
}
```

MSVC complains with "expression must have a constant value".
I was expecting the compiler to be clever enough to compile a version of `myMethod` with each possible version of the enum. Is that not the case ? Can I force it to, without an ugly switch in `doSomething` ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Somewhere you have to decide in run-time which `myMethod<Color>()` you want to call, if it's dependent of a non-constant variable. So, you are back to a `switch()` (or an if-else-cascade, or an array mapping colors to function pointers, or something else).

Comment: This seems to happen often recently. `const` doesn't make a (compile time) constant expresion, i.e. a expression that can be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: in a nutshell: template = compile time, ordinary function parameters = runtime. You can mix, but then you need to define how to mix, eg as already mentioned with a switch to choose which function to call

Comment: Fair enough, but irrelevant of the const expression, I still thought the compiler would somehow read out my enum and decide at runtime based on the value of the argument. Ok maybe I expect too much... Thank you for the help :)

Comment: What you might want to achieve, I once applied to a fun project to move `if`s out of the most inner loops to the outside. Of course, the nested loops had to be re-implemented for every case. There I used the template-with-value-parameters to prevent code duplication. [the template](https://github.com/scheff173/NoGL3dDemo/blob/master/RenderContext.cc#L333), the [call of that template](https://github.com/scheff173/NoGL3dDemo/blob/master/RenderContext.cc#L169) and a little explanation [Optimization Attempts](https://github.com/scheff173/NoGL3dDemo#optimization-attempts).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to decide between run-time or compile-time evaluation. The compile-time version can be something like this:

```
enum class Color { RED, BLACK };

template <Color c>
void myMethod () {
    if constexpr ( c == Color::RED ) { std::cout << "RED" << std::endl; }
    if constexpr ( c == Color::BLACK ) { std::cout << "BLACK" << std::endl; }
}   

int main()
{   
    myMethod<Color::RED>();
    myMethod<Color::BLACK>();
}
```

But, if you need to evaluate the variable at run-time, you have to switch over all of the possible values:

```
enum class Color { RED, BLACK };

template <Color c>  
void myMethod () {
    if constexpr ( c == Color::RED ) { std::cout << "RED" << std::endl; }
    if constexpr ( c == Color::BLACK ) { std::cout << "BLACK" << std::endl; }
}

void RuntimeDispatch( Color c ) 
{
    if ( c == Color::RED ) { myMethod<Color::RED>(); }
    if ( c == Color::BLACK ) { myMethod<Color::BLACK>(); }
}   

int main()
{   
    RuntimeDispatch( Color::RED );
    RuntimeDispatch( Color::BLACK );
}
```

There is simply no way to use a run-time variable as a template parameter, because the value is not a known constant at compile-time.

If you have to use an older compiler, you can replace `constexpr if` with template specialization:

```
template <Color c> void myMethod ();

template <> void myMethod<Color::RED>() { std::cout << "RED" << std::endl; }
template <> void myMethod<Color::BLACK>() { std::cout << "BLACK" << std::endl; }
```