# How can I use a enum variable as template argument?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, enums

If we have an enumeration type:

```
enum E {
   E1,
   E2,
   // ...
};
```

and based on `E`, a class template:

```
template <E T>
class C { /* ... */ };
```

Is there a way of using a **declared** variable of the type `E` as a template argument?

Example code:

```
E example_type = E1;
C<example_type> example_class;
```

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409984/c-enum-class-as-a-variable-template-parameter) answers your question? It uses a function parameter instead of a local/global variable.

Comment: if variable is `constexpr`, yes.

Comment: Could you clarify your example code? Currently it's not clear what you want, and your use of `C` makes no sense

Comment: Any reason you don't use `C<E1>`?

Comment: Depending on a string, I need to return an enum type. I want to use that type directly in another method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For integral (which an enumeration is) and arithmetic types, the template argument provided during instantiation must be a [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression). For example:

```
enum E {
   E1,
   E2,
};


template <E enum_val>
class Foo {
};

int main() {

    constexpr E var = E1;
    const E var2 = E2;
    Foo<var> foo;
    Foo<var2> foo2;

    E var3 = E2;
    Foo<var3> foo3;  // error: the value of ‘var3’ is not usable in a constant expression 
}
```